# Get X509Certificate2 Private and Public keys

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, .net-core

I have an existing application in .NET 4.5 where I use `X509Certificate2` private and public keys. I am migrating it to .net core. I am not getting how to read the private and public key values into XML format. I have below code in .NET 4.5

```
var PublicKey = certificate.PublicKey.Key.ToXmlString(false);
var PrivateKey = certificate.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true);
```

How do I achieve the same in .net core as the `PrivateKey` property is removed?

I am aware of the `ImportParameters` and `ExportParameters` methods to convert into XML strings. But what I am looking at is accessing `PublicKey.Key` and `PrivateKey` properties which gets me the `AsymmetricAlgorithm` object which could be casted to RSACrypoServiceProvider.

In .netCore there are methods `GetRSAPublicKey` and `GetRSAPrivateKey`, they return `RSACng` objects. The other side of the application which uses this certificate verifies data using `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

Comment: `PrivateKey` will be in .Net Core 2.0

Answer (score 4):

`X509Certificate2.PrivateKey` and `PublicKey.Key` were not brought over to .NET Core precisely because everyone cast them to `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.  While you get an `RSACng` on Windows, it's an `RSAOpenSsl` on Linux.

You should really just change all of the type references to `RSA`, since .NET 4.6 (and .NET Core 1.0) corrected the RSA base class to expose all of the required Sign/Verify//Encrypt/Decrypt methods.

.NET Core does not have the ability to read or write keys in the XML format. Even though the methods exist again for .NET Core 2.0 they just throw a `PlatformNotSupportedException`, since there's a circular dependency:

- Cryptography.Algorithms -> XML
- XML -> Networking (including TLS)
- Networking/TLS -> X509Certificates
- X509Certificates -> Cryptography.Algorithms

If you need the XML serialization of asymmetric keys you'll need to write it into your own libraries.

Comment: Agreed! But the application to which I pass my certificate is in older version of .net and verifies data using `RSACrytpoServiceProvider` . When I try calling using the certificates and SignedData created in .Net core (`RSA`)  I get Certificate Invalid and Signature invalid exception. How do I tackle this issue. And regarding converting into `XML` strings, yes, I have created my own extension methods.